# Undefined columns selected using panelvar package

Tags: undefined, panel

Have anyone used panel var in R?

Currently I'm using the package panelvar of R. And I'm getting this error :

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c(colnames(data)[panel_identifier], required_vars)) :
undefined columns selected
```

And my syntax currently is:

```
model1<-pvargmm(
    dependent_vars = c("Change.."),
    lags = 2,
    exog_vars = c("Price"),
transformation = "fd",    
data = base1,    
panel_identifier = c("id", "t"),
steps = c("twostep"),    
system_instruments = FALSE,    
max_instr_dependent_vars = 99,    
min_instr_dependent_vars = 2L,
collapse = FALSE)
```

I don't know why my panel_identifier is not working, it's pretty similar to the example given by panelvar package, however, it doesn't work, I want to appoint that base1 is on data.frame format. any ideas? Also, my data is structured like this:

```
 head(base1)
  id    t country    DDMMYY month month_text day Date_txt year    Price     Open
1  1 1296   China  1-4-2020     4        Apr   1   Apr 01 2020 12588.24 12614.82
2  1 1295   China 31-3-2020     3        Mar  31   Mar 31 2020 12614.82 12597.61

      High      Low Vol. Change..
1 12775.83 12570.32   NA  -0.0021
2 12737.28 12583.05   NA   0.0014
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation of the package and the [SSRN paper](https://ssrn.com/abstract=2896087). For me it helped to ensure all entered formats are identical (you can check this with `str(base1)` command). For example they write:

```
library(panelvar)
data("Dahlberg")
ex1_dahlberg_data <-
pvargmm(dependent_vars = .......
```

When I look at it I get

```
 >str(Dahlberg)
 'data.frame':  2385 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ id          : Factor w/ 265 levels "114","115","120",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
     $ year        : Factor w/ 9 levels "1979","1980",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 ...
     $ expenditures: num  0.023 0.0266 0.0273 0.0289 0.0226 ...
     $ revenues    : num  0.0182 0.0209 0.0211 0.0234 0.018 ...
     $ grants      : num  0.00544 0.00573 0.00566 0.00589 0.00559 ...
```

For example the input data must be a data.frame (in my case it had additional type specifications like tibble or data.table). I resolved it by casting `as.data.frame()` on it.